# What mean "Deep froze chain segment"?

Tags: go-ethereum, geth-debugging

I have question
My geth show me like that "Deep froze chain segment" repeatedly

What mean??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is related to Geth's Freezer functionality, which "moves ancient chain segments out of the active database into immutable append-only flat files."

The message you're seeing is informational, so it's nothing to worry about.

Geth's [`freeze()`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/46b437f39c66d228294acb76878fea890af77949/core/rawdb/freezer.go#L254) function (in `freezer.go`), where that message is output, does the following:

> "freeze is a background thread that periodically checks the
>   blockchain for any import progress and moves ancient data from the
>   fast database into the freezer."

Freezer was implemented in PR [#17814](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/pull/17814), and is described in detail in the PR.

Comment: `“Deep froze chain segment”`message  is followed by `message loop` should I worry about it?

Comment: Hmm, not sure. Can't immediately see where that is in the code. So the actual message is "message loop"?

Comment: Yes keep repeating itself on a mesage loop

Comment: If you look at the hash ID you'll probably see that the message is not so much repeating itself as repeatedly doing a similar thing.